# Cookies Consent - re-sending page view event?

Tags: google-analytics

I am not sure about Google Analytics behaviour in sending allowAdFeatures.

I added analytics.js the default way, setting only the tracker:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX', 'example.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

When the user lands on my site, I show him a popup asking him to approve saving cookies.

Upon his approval I send:

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', false);
ga('set', 'allowAdFeatures', true);
```

My question is about the current page that he is viewing (before approving the consent) - will the action of page view be able to be re-targeted for that current user or I need to send another event of page view?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to send another page or an event with the new settings in order to send the updated data to Analytics.

However, you don't need to send this with your second hit:

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', false);
```

Rather this with the previous pageview (and nothing with the second):

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

anonymizeIp is not active by deafult, so you must declare it in the initial code.

Comment: meaning sending again ga("send", "pageview") after the user approves the consent? wouldn't Google count it as 2 views from the same person?

Comment: I don't like to send a second pageview either, so I suggested to possibly send an event. The fact is that if the user, after accepting the cookie policy, does nothing else, he will not contribute to the collection of socio-demographic data, therefore enabling allowAdFeatures will have no effect.